# Flutter : can't align text field in the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, uitextfield

I'm trying to Align Text Field in the bottom lest but it is still in the same position in screen .
this is  my code for that

```
Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                            // height: 60,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                        const Radius.circular(5.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                controller: commentController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

can anyone help me !

Comment: Can you show image for what you are expecting as result ?

Answer (score 0):

The container that the Align widget is smaller than the height of the screen.  Make sure that container is that big.  Flutter Inspector works well for this.

Comment: can you explain in more details please !

Comment: We'll need more of the code to that page/screen.